# Library for working with recurrence rules in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, datetime, ios, nsdate

I'd like to do some reasoning about recurrence rules in an Objective C application (targetted at iOS currently). I'd like to do things like work out when the next occurrence of a particular event is from a given point, or whether a particular date & time falls within a given rule.

Previously I've written such code in python with the [dateutil rrule module](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57), which works quite nicely, but haven't yet found a nice Objective C equivalent. There is a class in the Calendar Framework that sounds like it'd be useful, [CalRecurrenceRule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CalRecurrenceRule_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but there doesn't seem to be any way to reason about the objects it produces, so is of no help.

Having written lots of time code in python, I know that getting it right is hard, so I'd like to avoid writing recurrence logic myself, so if anyone can recommend a library that might do what I want that can be used in an iOS application, that'd be much appreciated.

-- Michael

Comment: Pretty sure CalRecurrenceRule is Mac OS X only (i.e.: not iOS), but I've updated your question to link to the relevant class reference doc.

Comment: Thanks middaparka - my bad on the Mac only Calendar Framework. Means I'm further away from a solution than I'd hoped.

Answer (score 0):

`CalRecurrenceRule` is a class that exists on the Mac as part of the CalendarStore framework.  It does not exist on iOS.  The iOS equivalent is the EventKit framework, which has its own [`EKRecurrenceRule`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009569) class.  What are you wanting to do with these recurrence rules?

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the CalendarStore framework!

What I'd like to be able to do is reason about recurring calendar entries. In particular I'd like to know for a given set of rules the start time of the occurrence that happens before now (the before method in the python rrule module). Given that information and the duration of the entry I can work out if any rules are currently active.

I'd also like to work out the first occurrence after now too, so I can build an event list so I know when to trigger transitions based on entries.

Hope that makes sense!